# Any examples for Numpy asanyarray vs asarray?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, data-science

I am looking for some examples which shows the difference between [`numpy.asanyarray()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.asanyarray.html) and [`numpy.asarray()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.asarray.html)? And at which conditions should I use specifically asanyarray()?

Answer (score 14):

Code for `asanyarray`:

```
return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order, subok=True)
```

for `asarray`:

```
return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
```

The only difference is in specifying the `subok` parameter.  If you are working with subclasses of `ndarray` you might want to use it.  If you don't know what that means, it probably doesn't matter.

The defaults for `np.array` are:

```
array(object, dtype=None, copy=True, order='K', subok=False, ndmin=0)
```

If you are fine tuning a function that is supposed to work with all kinds of numpy arrays (and lists that can be made into arrays), and shouldn't make unnecessary copies, you can use one of these functions.  Otherwise `np.array`, without or without the extra prameters, works just fine.  As a beginner don't put much effort into understanding these differences.

===

`expand_dims` uses both:

```
if isinstance(a, matrix):
    a = asarray(a)
else:
    a = asanyarray(a)
```

A `np.matrix` subclass array can only have 2 dimensions, but `expand_dims` has to change that, so uses `asarray` to turn the input into a regular `ndarray`.  Otherwise it uses `asanyarray`.  That way a subclass like maskedArray remains that class.

```
In [158]: np.expand_dims(np.eye(2),1)                                           
Out[158]: 
array([[[1., 0.]],

       [[0., 1.]]])
In [159]: np.expand_dims(np.matrix(np.eye(2)),1)                                
Out[159]: 
array([[[1., 0.]],

       [[0., 1.]]])
In [160]: np.expand_dims(np.ma.masked_array(np.eye(2)),1)                       
Out[160]: 
masked_array(
  data=[[[1., 0.]],

        [[0., 1.]]],
  mask=False,
  fill_value=1e+20)
```